# Не получается спарсить данные с сайта

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

Хочу спарсить счета матчей с сайта https://www.championat.com/football/_spain/tournament/5047/teams/232369/result/

Написал такой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r = requests.get("https://www.championat.com/football/_spain/tournament/5047/teams/232369/result/")
html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

for el in html.select(".page-content"):
    title = el.select(".stat-results__count-main > ._win > span")
    print(title[0].text)
```

Но почему-то он не работает. Можете подсказать, что может быть не так?

Comment: с таких сайтов вроде бы не так просто это сделать

Comment: Если Вам помог мой ответ, отметине, пожалуйста, его как ответ на Ваш вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых, вам нужно подключить в проект библиотеку fake_useragent, поскольку большенство сайтов (в том числе и требуемый вам) сразу же обрубают соединение если видят пустой UserAgent в заголовке запроса.

Во вторых, вам нужно немного изменить логику поиска нужного html элемента.

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r = requests.get("https://www.championat.com/football/_spain/tournament/5047/teams/232369/result/", headers={'User-Agent': UserAgent().random})
html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

for el in html.select(".stat-results__count-main"):
    print(el.text.strip())
```